# What is an aggressive grass that will grow from seed in Maine?

Tags: lawn, grass

My lawn is a hodgepodge of different grass types - notably Bermuda grass on my front lawn.

Is there a grass that you can seed that will push other grasses out?

For reference I live in Maine.

Edit:

Based on answers below, I should concede to the Bermuda grass. So, I'll leave the front lawn out of the equation. So with the hodge podge of grasses in my side and back lawn, is there a grass that can make it all cohesive? Or do I seed bermuda grass everywhere?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Bermuda grass is not to be trifled with. It is determined to call your lawn home and won't leave without a fight. To put it simply you wont be able to push it out with any other grasses. That would be like the plot of the Cat in the Hat, every solution turned into another problem. If you want it gone, you'll have to properly kill it all and replant since it spreads [underground](http://www.sunset.com/garden/earth-friendly/how-to-remove-bermuda-grass-00400000052080/). Killing it effectively will take several applications of roundup or some potent [herbicide.](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B005DUTNF0) If you do go the herbicide route, be sure to mix it with a surfactant to increase the coverage.

Comment: If the bermuda grass is so hard to get rid of, why not just fill with bermuda? A lawn grass that will essentially *never* die seems ideal to me...

Comment: see edit above.

Answer (score 3):

I like bstpierre's comment just embrace it, but it is hard to get ride of, but if you are looking for a non-chemical approach lay a tarp over it ever day for a month, but do not trap the moisture at night. This is not the best solution but besides digging it up ( roots are around 6 inches down ), which is not that straight forward.....you do not have many options

Answer (score 3):

Zoysia grass is very aggressive and will push out weeds and other grasses.
I just don't know how well it will grow in Maine.